# Separating CSV file with split function and IGNORING quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, csv, split

I have this string from a csv file = "10","100","11","1"
and i would like to split it on **Java** into an array like this:

`10,100,11,1`

I've been using this piece of code for that but i need to add a part to "Not include quotes", is that
possible? if not, how could i easily get just the **integer values** from it?

```
String str = "\"10\",\"100\",\"11\",\"1\"";
String[] tokens = str.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What's your desired result type? Does it matter? Maybe an `int[]`, a `List<Integer>` or an `Integer[]`? It's all possible...

Comment: @deHaar Every splitted value goes as an integer to an arraylist, but as far as i get  how to delete the quoutes,i can handle the rest, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to use a solution that does not need a regular expression but uses the stream API instead, you could just `split` the `String` by comma, stream the results, remove the double quotes around each item and parse it to an `int`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "\"10\",\"100\",\"11\",\"1\"";
    // stream the results of splitting by comma
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
                                // parse the int after removíng the double-quotes
                                .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replace("\"", "")))
                                // and return a list of integers
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // then print the integers
    numbers.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This outputs

```
10
100
11
1
```

As an alternative, you could also create an `int[]` instead of a `List<Integer>`, here's how to do that (with the same output as shown above):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "\"10\",\"100\",\"11\",\"1\"";
    // stream the results of splitting by comma
    int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(str.split(","))
                                // parse and map to int after removíng the double-quotes
                                .mapToInt(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replace("\"", "")))
                                // and make it an array
                                .toArray();
    // then print the integers
    Arrays.stream(numbers).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: This is the complete answer. I missed the requirement that OP also needed each string to be converted into an `int`.

Comment: Your answer really helped me to google and study streams (new for me!!) , my bad i didnt specify that i have to use regex, ill learn a bit more of streams because every external library or api on my code must to be written on my report (college proyect) thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can get `String[]` simply as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\"10\",\"100\",\"11\",\"1\"";

        // Replace double quote with blank
        str = str.replace("\"", "");

        // Split the resulting string on comma
        String[] arr = str.split(",");

        // Display the resulting array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[10, 100, 11, 1]
```

**Alternatively,**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.MatchResult;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "\"10\",\"100\",\"11\",\"1\"";
        List<Integer> list=Pattern.compile("\\d+")
                          .matcher(str)
                          .results()
                          .map(MatchResult::group)
                          .map(Integer::valueOf)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Note that the alternative solution returns `List<Integer>`. If you need `List<String>` remove `.map(Integer::valueOf)` from it.

Comment: Note that this is only reasonable if the data doesnt need the quotes (so no strings or localized floats with actual commas inside).

Comment: @Zabuzard - I completely agree with you. My answer is purely based on the input and output mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Zabuzard good point, but OP clearly shows interest in **integer values**, so I think this answer does most of the desired work, but skips the type conversion.

Comment: Nice alternative... `Pattern.compile`, didn't even think about it.

Comment: Thanks! str = str.replace("\"", ""); helped me, but later i have to work with CSV with data that is really random with commas and necesary quoutes, as @Zabuzard mentioned, but this plus my regex code may work, thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```java
String str = "\"10\",\"100\",\"11\",\"1\"";

String[] arr = str.replaceAll("(^\"|\"$)","").split("\",\"");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```